# Scala: override type method

Tags: scala

I have a Scala `object` containing the definition of a `type`.
I am now willing to change the behavior of the type by overriding its `equals` method. Is it possibile?

The code I have right now is the following:

```
object CallGraph {
type CallTree = LinkedTree[Enter]
}
```

And I'd like to override the `equal` method for the `CallTree` type

Comment: please explain more fully, and include code to show what you are asking.

Comment: maybe you mean `class CallTree extends LinkedTree[Enter] { override def equals(x: Any) = ... }`

Comment: That's probably better. Type works just for renaming, does it?

Comment: They are basically an alias, but you can also have abstract types which act like generics, so they're more than that.

Comment: any answers to this? looking for the same thing

Comment: I solved defining a new class, as recommended by @LuigiPlinge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is not a type definition but a type declaration.
Something like `type SomeName = SomeType` is just an alias. In addition to just giving an alias like it is done here, a type declaration can include a type parameter and can also be used to declare the upper and lower bound of a type.
In order to change override a method, you really need to define your new type using a class as already pointed out by Luigi Plinge.